# Manually Installed new Python to /usr/bin, how to get Repo version back?

Tags: apt, python, python-2.7

Yes, I'm a moron, and I tried to manually install a higher point release of python 2.7.16 to /usr/bin/  (i did `./configure --prefix=/usr`) on my Ubuntu 16.04 machine. It seems to work fine EXCEPT for packages that depended on python, like `apt-listchanges`, which fails with messages like `ImportError: No module named apt_pkg`

there's no `make uninstall` available, I've tried manually removing files, and still when I try `apt --reinstall install python`, Nothing gets overwritten and the python executable still gives the new `2.7.16` version...

Any idea how to get the official repository version back??

Comment: Try `apt install --reinstall python2.7-minimal`, that should bring back python 2.7.12

Comment: Dude thank you so much, you are a lifesaver. I had already tried reinstalling python-minimal and python, but this did the trick! For anyone else that sees this, to be safe what I did was `apt --reinstall install libpython-stdlib libpython2.7-minimal libpython2.7-stdlib python python-minimal python2.7 python2.7-minimal`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To find out which package installed a file you can use `apt-file`, you can install it with

```
sudo apt install apt-file
```

and find the package with

```
apt-file search /path/to/file
```

so in this case

```
apt-file search /usr/bin/python
```

which revealed `python2.7-minimal`, reinstalling this package solved the problem,
in this case OP reinstalled some other packages as well to be sure everything works fine:

```
apt --reinstall install libpython-stdlib libpython2.7-minimal libpython2.7-stdlib python python-minimal python2.7 python2.7-minimal
```